# Can Anylogic be integrated with a VR device?

Tags: simulation, virtual-reality, anylogic, oculus

Do you know if there is any way to integrate Anylogic with a VR device to see the simulation run in VR? What type of software/methodology has worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only possible as far as you can run any Windows application in VR (i.e. in "cinema mode"). But there is no automated way to really "visit" your models in VR.

However, there may be some Java packages that could help, but it would be custom coding

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, as always. I can work on the models through windows, but as you said, I want to "visit" the world of the model.  Can you tell me which Java packages you know that could be useful please?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry :) Another idea is to use VR-ready 3D packages like Unity (?) and animate your model there. i.e. use AnyLogic for modelling and Unity to animate. This is doable (check some recent AL conf papers)